# Cannot end a section without first starting one in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so I keep getting this error Cannot end a section without first starting one in Laravel on my website online but localhost it is working no problem I don't see anything wrong with the code and I tried changing @stop with @endsection still the same, and I repeat I got this error on my online website, not my localhost my localhost is working fine, btw when I removed the heading section the error is gone but I need it.

here's my code

```
@extends('AdminPanel.master.main')
@section('heading')
    Banner Details
    <a style="float: right" href="/admin/banners-list" class="btn btn-primary">
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> Back To List
    </a>
@stop
@section('body')
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="margin-bottom: 2%">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#tab_a" data-toggle="tab">English</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_b" data-toggle="tab">العربية </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_c" data-toggle="tab">Urdu </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab_d" data-toggle="tab">Chinese </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active  login-tabs" id="tab_a">
                    <table class="table table-hover profile">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Title</td>
                                <td> {{$data->TitleEn}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Caption</td>
                                <td> {{$data->CaptionEn}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Image</td>
                                <td><img @if($data->Image)src="/admin-assests/banner/{{$data->Image}}" @endif width="200px"
                                 height="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane  login-tabs" id="tab_b">
                    <table class="table table-hover profile">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>العنوان</td>
                                <td> {{$data->TitleAr}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>الوصف</td>
                                <td> {{$data->CaptionAr}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Image</td>
                                <td><img @if($data->Image)src="/admin-assests/banner/{{$data->Image}}" @endif width="200px"
                                 height="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane  login-tabs" id="tab_c">
                    <table class="table table-hover profile">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>العنوان</td>
                                <td> {{$data->TitleUr}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>الوصف</td>
                                <td> {{$data->CaptionUr}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Image</td>
                                <td><img @if($data->Image)src="/admin-assests/banner/{{$data->Image}}" @endif width="200px"
                                 height="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane  login-tabs" id="tab_d">
                    <table class="table table-hover profile">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>العنوان</td>
                                <td> {{$data->TitleCh}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>الوصف</td>
                                <td> {{$data->CaptionCh}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>Image</td>
                                <td><img @if($data->Image)src="/admin-assests/banner/{{$data->Image}}" @endif width="200px"
                                 height="200px"></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 pull-right">
            <a href="/admin/banner/{{$data->BannerID}}/edit/" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Edit Info</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

main

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @include('AdminPanel.master.head')
    @include('AdminPanel.master.navbar')
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">@yield('heading')</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    @yield('body')
</div>
    @include('AdminPanel.master.footer')
</body>
```

Comment: use @endsection and what is the code of @extends('AdminPanel.master.main')

Comment: have you done `@yield('heading')` &  `@yield('body')` properly in the main.blade.php ?

Comment: @lagbox laravel 5.5

Comment: Try using `@endsection` instead of `@stop`

Comment: Can you try using `@section('heading')@show` instead of `@yield('heading')`. Same with the 'body'.

Also, use `@endsection` instead of `@stop`

Comment: where did you even see `@stop`? ... not the docs for 5.5

Comment: @lagbox well its working in localhost as i said and i tried to use  endsection the same error

Comment: @Joe i tried that

Comment: good luck to you

Comment: stop and endsection are the same.  Anyway, try changing 'heading' to something else, like 'pagehead' if it works without it, it might be a conflict.

Comment: @GoatHater I tried that still same error the thing is that i get the error from this page only

Comment: Check your includes too! (head, navbar, footer) Maybe, they're the ones causing the error.

Comment: @PaulSantos only this page gives this error and when its on my online server, i have no problems with this page in my localhost

Comment: Sorry to ask you but have you checked if your local and server source code are in synced?

Comment: @PaulSantos yes i full deployed the website but still the same problem